# radio button selection using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I need help for i had develop the radio buttons one is cheque and anothewr one is online- transfer when ever user click cheque it displays one form and if user click online-transfer it display another form using java script ok it is working but click one radio button after refresh the browser no form can be displayed.Here is below attached my code please verify and suggest me.
html code:

```
<html>

<head>
<script text="text/javascript">
function optionChanged()
{
var a=document.withdrawform;
if(a.withdraw_by[0].checked)
{

a.reset();a.withdraw_by[0].checked=true;
document.getElementById("cheque_msg").style.visibility="visible";
document.getElementById("cheque_msg").style.display="block";
document.getElementById("accountInfo").style.visibility="hidden";
document.getElementById("accountInfo").style.display="none";
}
else
{
a.reset();a.withdraw_by[1].checked=true;
document.getElementById("accountInfo").style.visibility="visible";
document.getElementById("accountInfo").style.display="block";
document.getElementById("cheque_msg").style.visibility="hidden";
document.getElementById("cheque_msg").style.display="none";
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<!--<a target="popup" onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/','name','width=600,height=400')">Open page in new window</a>-->

<div class="main_content">
    <p class="ca_head">Withdraw Cash</p>
        <ul class="step_bar"> 
            <li>1. Give your information</li> 
            <li class="active">2. Select Withdraw Option</li> 
        </ul>
        <form id="withdrawform" name="withdrawform" method="post" action="withdraw-confirmation.html" onsubmit="clearErrors();">        
            <input type="hidden" name="bankAccount" id="bankAccount" value="0"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="monthlyWithdraw" id="monthlyWithdraw" value="0"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="withdrawableBalance" id="withdrawableBalance" value="0.37"/>             
            <input type="hidden" id="ecsCharge" value="0"/>
            <input type="hidden" id="chequeCharge" value="0"/>
            <input type="hidden" id="freeWithdrawCount" value="0"/>
            <input type="hidden" id="withdrawError" value=""/>
            <input type="hidden" name="ifsc" id="ifsc" value="N"/>
            <div class="content_area">
            <h3 class="sub_head">Submit your withdraw request for processing</h3>
            <div class="form_row">
                <label>Your Withdrawable Balance <strong>:</strong></label>
                <strong><span class="rupeefont">r&nbsp;</span>&nbsp;0.37</strong>
            </div>
            <div class="form_row">
                <label for="new_mobile">Withdraw by <strong>:</strong></label>
                <div class="flt_lt wid_256" id="withdraw_options">
                    <label class="lbl_flt">
                        <input type="radio" name="withdraw_by" id="withdraw_by" onclick="optionChanged()" value="Cheque" /> Cheque                      
                    </label>
                    <label class="lbl_flt">
                        <input type="radio" name="withdraw_by" id="withdraw_by" onclick="optionChanged()" value="Online Transfer"/> Online Transfer
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>  
            <div id="cheque_msg" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"><span><p style="color:RED" align="justify">Please Note that Withdrawal by cheque would take upto 12 working days. Online Transfer is a much faster
option.Also, cheque would be dispatched to your regsitered mailing address.Submit your withdrawal request only if the address below is valid.If you wish to
update your address,please write to fairplay@RummyNo1.com along with your address proof.
            </p>
            <div class="form_row">
                <label for="trackAmount">Enter the Amount <strong>:</strong></label>
                <input type="text" name="trackAmount" id="trackAmount" class="flt_lt" style="width:138px;" maxlength="15"/>
            </div>

            </div>


            <div id="accountInfo" style="display: none;">
                <div class="form_row" style="position:relative;">



                    <div class="form_row">
                        <label for="accountNumber">Account number <strong>:</strong></label>
                        <input type="text" maxlength="45" name="accountNumber" id="accountNumber" class="flt_lt" style="width:138px;"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form_row">
                        <label for="reAccountNumber">Re enter account number <strong>:</strong></label>
                        <input type="text" maxlength="45" name="reAccountNumber" id="reAccountNumber" class="flt_lt" style="width:138px;"/>                     
                    </div>
                    <div class="form_row">
                        <label for="micr">MICR Code <a href="javascript:openMicrPopup();" class="imagelink"><!-- <img src="https://rcmg.in/rc/icon_info.png"  border="0" />--></a>&nbsp;<strong> :</strong></label>
                        <input type="text" maxlength="9" name="micr" id="micr" class="flt_lt" style="width:138px;" />                               
                    </div>
                    <div class="form_row">
                        <label for="reMicr">Re enter MICR code <strong>:</strong></label>
                        <input type="text" maxlength="9" name="reMicr" id="reMicr" class="flt_lt" style="width:138px;"/>
                    </div>                  


            <div class="form_row">
                        <label for="ifsc_code">IFSC Code <a href="javascript:openIfscPopup();" class="imagelink"><!-- <img src="https://rcmg.in/rc/icon_info.png"  border="0" />--></a>&nbsp;<strong>:</strong></label>
                        <input type="text" maxlength="11" name="ifsc_code" id="ifsc_code" class="flt_lt" style="width:138px;" onkeypress="return onlyAlphaNumericsForIfsc(event)" />                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="form_row">
                        <label for="bank_name">Bank Name <strong>:</strong></label>
                        <input type="text" maxlength="30" name="bank_name" id="bank_name" class="flt_lt" style="width:138px;" onkeypress="return onlyAlphaNumerics(event)" />                       
                    </div>
                    <div class="form_row">
                        <label for="branch_name">Branch Name <strong>:</strong></label>
                        <input type="text" maxlength="30" name="branch_name" id="branch_name" class="flt_lt" style="width:138px;" onkeypress="return onlyAlphaNumerics(event)" />                       
                    </div>

            </div>

            <div class="form_row">
                <label for="trackAmount">Enter the Amount <strong>:</strong></label>
                <input type="text" name="trackAmount" id="trackAmount" class="flt_lt" style="width:138px;" maxlength="15"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form_row" id="withdrawButton">
                <label>&nbsp;</label>
                <input type="submit" name="submit_btn" title="Continue" value="Continue" class="btn_submit" id="withdrawsubmit"/>
            </div>  
            <p class="info_txt">
                For more information on service charges and withdrawing cash from your account, 
                <a href="javascript:openInfoPopup();" title="Information on Withdrawing Cash">click here</a>. 
            </p>
            <!-- &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; -->
        </div>
    </form>
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What does your console say?

Comment: after select radio button refresh the browser no form can be dispalyed but radio button ius selected @ Miss Chetan Gawai

Comment: Do you get any error in console?

Comment: no@ Miss Chetan Gawai

Comment: it is working but i want after select the radio button refresh the browser radio button is in selected state but radio button related form not displayed@ Miss Chetan Gawai